# Binding ObservableCollection to DataGrid ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I am trying to bind the items of the ComboBox with an ObservableCollection, I have been successfully binding them to a `StaticResource`,

The XAML, `Nursing_Home_Name` is the SQL Server Table and this code works fine for me.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CollectionsLists x:Key="StaticNursingHomeList" />
</Window.Resources>


<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="120" Header="施設名称">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                           Path=Nursing_Home_Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <ComboBox Text="{Binding Path=Nursing_Home_Name,
                           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding NursingHome, 
                           Source={StaticResource StaticNursingHomeList}}" />
       </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And code behind,

```
class CollectionsLists
    {     
        public static List<string> NursingHome { get; set; } 
        var homeNames = Database.GetNursingHomeNames(_nursingHomeSection);
        if (homeNames != null)
        {
           NursingHome = new List<string>();
           foreach (var item in homeNames)
           {
                NursingHome.Add(item);
           }
        }
    }
```

---

**Now for the problem code,**

I am finding it very hard to debug the XAML on what I am doing wrong.

This is the code behind,

```
public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {        
        public MainWindow()
        { 
            DataContext = this; 
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> _nursingHomeNames = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public ObservableCollection<string> NursingHomeNames
           {
               get { return _nursingHomeNames; }
               set
               {
                   _nursingHomeNames = value;
                   NotifyPropertyChanged();
               }
           }
}
```

And I cannot show the multitude of ways that I have tried to get the XAML to work, but instead I will post what I thought was the closest to getting it to work,

The XAML, `Nursing_Home_Name` is the SQL Server Table BTW

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="120" Header="施設名称">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                           Path=Nursing_Home_Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <ComboBox Text="{Binding Path=Nursing_Home_Name,
                           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding NursingHomeNames}" />
       </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**What do I need to add to get this to bind correctly?**

Comment: As a note (again), setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has no effect in a OneWay binding, like the one on the `TextBlock.Text` property. It's also unclear why you would bind the ComboBox's Text property instead of SelectedItem or SelectedValue.

Comment: @Clemens, I though that if you did not specify that binding is always TwoWay?

Comment: Yet another misunderstanding. The binding mode is either set explicitly, or defaults to a value that dependends on the target property. UpdateSourceTrigger doesn't change that. However, UpdateSourceTrigger (as its name implies) controls when source updates are triggered, and only has an effect if the source is updated after all.

Comment: @Clemens, OK, I think I understand now. Still relatively new to binding, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Clemens , Well, of coarse you are correct. I just figured out that I don't need to make a static property (my other question) and that binding the the `TextBlock` is a waste of time. Ahh well, that is what learning is all about I guess. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I need to add to get this to bind correctly?

Since NursingHomeNames is a property of the parent window and the DataContext of the ComboBox is an item in the ItemsSource collection of the DataGrid, you need to specify the window as the source of the binding. Try this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NursingHomeNames, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Nursing_Home_Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Comment: Well that did it for me. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Binding in WPF uses what's called the `DataContext` of current context. In your case `DataContext` is of your `MainWindow` and know this that you can't have two of these in one context for example you can declare another one inside your `DataGrid` but you can't use the one from `MainWindow` any more.
In short you can't bind to `Nursing_Home_Name` and `NursingHomeNames` in the same context.

Ok what's the solution then?

You have to bring one of these properties to the other context. It's simpler to bring your `Nursing_Home_Name` to your `MainWindow` like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{        
    public MainWindow()
    { 
        DataContext = this; 
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _nursingHomeNames = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> NursingHomeNames
       {
           get { return _nursingHomeNames; }
           set { _nursingHomeNames = value; }
       }

    public string Nursing_Home_Name //Unconventional name. But I kept your naming
    {
        get { return GetNursingHomeNameFromDB(); }
        set 
        {
            SaveNursingHomeName(value); 
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Nursing_Home_Name");
        }
    }
}
```

This will work if you implement `GetNursingHomeNameFromDB` and `SaveNursingHomeName`.

One final tip: `ObservableCollection<T>` doesn't require `NotifyPropertyChanged()` it's built in.

Comment: `Nursing_Home_Name` is not a string, it is a `Database Table` and I bind to that so as I can update the database with any data changes.

Comment: No no you are not using the correct approach here. Binding is not for such an operation. You have to listen for property changed event and do the operation there. Also read my initial explanations.

Comment: What does the two methods `SaveNursingHomeName` and `GetNursingHomeNameFromDB()` look like?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not what you need. Your structure is unknown to me. In my opinion you must have two tables one is for Nursing Homes and another for example, for people in them. Now in the list of people you have a drop down which selects the nursing home these people are in.... If that's the case I can help otherwise I need more info. Please edit your question.

Comment: Yes, I have a table that I get the nursing home names from and populate a `List<T>` as in my OP. I then use that list to populate the ComboBox. But, instead of using a `List<T>` and a `Static Resource` for binding, I want to bind directly to an `ObservableCollection` to populate the ComboBox.

Comment: Combobox has two properties one list of items and other the selected item. What you want is a static list of items which comes from the `NursingHomeNames` property and the other is the dynamic want and that you want to save to db in case of any changes. That's one (not a list) item and linked to your people table not your list of homes. The way I said is how you do it then. Save the `Nursing_Home_Name` in your people table.

Comment: OK, I understand that, but what do those two methods look like? Cheers